# Internals for python tuples

Tags: python, tuples, python-internals

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=1
>>> id(a)
140472563599848
>>> id(b)
140472563599848
>>> x=()
>>> y=()
>>> id(x)
4298207312
>>> id(y)
4298207312
>>> x1=(1)
>>> x2=(1)
>>> id(x1)
140472563599848
>>> id(x2)
140472563599848
```

until this point I was thinking there will be only one copy of immutable object and that will be shared(pointed) by all the variables.

But when I tried, the below steps I understood that I was wrong.

```
>>> x1=(1,5)
>>> y1=(1,5)
>>> id(x1)
4299267248
>>> id(y1)
4299267320
```

can anyone please explain me the internals?

Comment: Note, this is an implementation detail, not something that can be depended on. And building constants is one thing while something dyamic like `tuple(range(3))` several times is not interned and you get separate objects. You only get interning when the compiler can figure out the value.

Comment: `x1=(1)` **does not make a tuple**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> x1=(1)
>>> x2=(1)
```

is actually the same as

```
>>> x1=1
>>> x2=1
```

In Python, [smaller numbers are internally cached](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/1903116). So they will not be created in the memory multiple times. That is why `id`s of `x1` and `x2` are the same till this point.

An one element tuple should have a comma at the end, like this

```
>>> x1=(1,)
>>> x2=(1,)
```

When you do this, there are two new tuples to be constructed with only one element in it. Even though the elements inside the tuples are the same, they both are different tuples. That is why they both have different `id`s.

Lets take your last example and disassemble the code.

```
compiled_code = compile("x1 = (1, 5); y1 = (1, 5)", "string", "exec")
```

Now,

```
import dis
dis.dis(compiled_code)
```

would produce something like this

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ((1, 5))
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (x1)
              6 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 5))
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (y1)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

It loads a constant value, referred by the index `3`, which is `(1, 5)` and then stores it in `x1`. The same way, it loads another constant value, at index `4` and stores it in `y1`. If we look at the list of constants in the code object,

```
print(compiled_code.co_consts)
```

will give

```
(1, 5, None, (1, 5), (1, 5))
```

The elements at positions `3` and `4` are the tuples which we created in the actual code. So, Python doesn't create only one instance for every immutable object, *always*. Its an implementation detail which we don't have to worry much about anyway.

**Note:** If you want to have only one instance of an immutable object, you can manually do it like this

```
x1 = (1, 5)
x2 = x1
```

Now, both `x2` and `x1` will refer the same tuple object.

Comment: @JonClements Included that in the answer now :-)

Comment: I'd like to mention that this behavior has actually changed (as of Python 3.9, although I'm not sure in which version exactly it changed). Now it seems that the Python compiler tries to reuse tuples for code that is "compiled together" (not sure how exactly that works), so if you enter `x = (1, 5); y = (1, 5)` (as one line) in the interactive shell, `x is y` will in fact be true. However, if you enter `x = (1, 5)` and `y = (1, 5)` as two lines in the interactive shell, then they will still have different ids (unlike small integers and strings).

Comment: In my 3.10, `compiled_code.co_consts` is `((1, 5), None)` - the tuple was interned. In fact, if you do `x1=(1,)`, `x2=(1,)` in a function in the shell, or anywhere in a .py file, it'll be interned as a single tuple. I think that just highlights how this is just an implementation detail and can change whenever.

Answer (score 1):

As of Python3.7 tuple creation uses *interning*.

```
t1 = (1, 2, 3)
t2 = (1, 2, 3)
print(t2 is t1)
```

The above code prints `True` for Python version 3.7 and above.

But in the Python shell, it behaves differently; tuples don't reference to single object like string literals.

```
>>> t1 = (1, 2, 3)
>>> t2 = (1, 2, 3)
>>> t2 is t1
False
```

Comment: It will depend on how its compiled - do it in the shell / repl, and you'll get two different objects because each line is compiled separately. Do it in a .py file or a function in the repl, they'll be the same.

Comment: So, this specific behavior is probably is due to the improvements of constant folding in 3.7,  the removing of the peep-hole bytecode optimizer with an optimizer that works on the AST instead.